# What's the formula for the sum of integers between n and m?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, formula, reduce

I am looking at this challenge:

> The formula to compute the sum from 1 to n is:
>
> **total = n * (n + 1) / 2**
>
> Write a function that computes the sum of all values between **n** and **m**, inclusive.
>
> Is there some way to use that formula, **n**, and **m** to get the answer? Think outside the box... You don't have to come up with a new formula; there's a way to use the existing one to solve it.

I still passed all of the tests by writing this code:

```js
function solution(n, m){
    let numsArr = [];
    for(i=n; i <= m; i++){
        numsArr.push(i);
    }
    let initialValue = 0;
    let sum = numsArr.reduce(
        (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
        initialValue
    );
    return sum
}

console.log(solution(5,9));
```

But how do I solve it using the specified formula?

Comment: f(m) - f(n - 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you want is the difference between sum up to `m` minus sum up to `n-1`.

```js
const sum = (a) => a * (a + 1) / 2;

const mySum = (m, n) => sum(m) - sum(n - 1);

console.log(mySum(9, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is `((m - n) / 2 + n) * (m - n + 1)`.

First get the `average` between `m` and `n`: `((m - n) / 2 + n)`.

Then multiply it by the numbers count: `(m - n + 1)`.

```js
const average = ((m - n) / 2 + n)
const numbersCount = (m - n + 1)
const result = average * numbersCount
```